# MechanicalSoup doesn't catch the selected data

Tags: python-3.5, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to use following code. But i get  5 times the same data of the first selected date.

```
import re
import datetime
import mechanicalsoup

def get_EminiTable(soup):
    allValues = []
    colnames = soup.find('thead').get_text()
    allValues.append([i for i in colnames.split('\n') if len(i) > 1])
    lnr = 0
    for line in soup.tbody.find_all('tr'):
        allValues.append([i for i in line.get_text().split('\n') if len(i) > 0])
        if 'UNCH' in allValues:
            allValues.pop()
        if lnr > 1: break
        lnr += 1
    return allValues

def get_settldays(soup):
    settlDays = soup.find('select', id="cmeTradeDate").get
    settlDays = re.findall('\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d',str(settlDays))
    return [datetime.datetime.strptime(adat, '%m/%d/%Y') for adat in settlDays]


url =  "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html"
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
if str(browser.open(url)) != '<Response [200]>':
    print('Error')
    quit()
soup = browser.get_current_page()
settlDays = get_settldays(soup)
for adate in settlDays:
    form = browser.select_form('form[id="quotesoptionsform1"]')
    form.set("tradeDate",adate.__format__('%m/%d/%Y'))
    browser.submit_selected()
    soup = browser.get_current_page()
    tabvals = get_EminiTable(soup)
    print(adate)
    for each in tabvals:
        print(each)
browser.session.close()
browser.close()
```

any idea to get the correct date of the different tables, or is it a bug in mechanicalsoup.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason is because this form is handled by JavaScript, not HTTP, and so submitting the form with an HTTP request (which is how MechanicalSoup works) doesn't actually do anything.

MechanicalSoup creates a request URL with the following syntax:

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html?action=Submit&tradeDate=12%2F15%2F2017

If you click this link, you can see that the query string `&action=Submit&tradeDate=12%2F15%2F2017` is ignored. Whereas if we set the trade date by hand in a real web browser, we see that it appends `#tradeDate=12/15/2017` to the URL.

Even if I take that URL from the web browser and open it with MechanicalSoup, it does not display correctly because the JavaScript isn't processed. You can see this by modifying your last for-loop in the following way:

```
for adate in settlDays:
    # Open the URL for each date directly
    date = adate.__format__('%m/%d/%Y')
    resp = browser.open(url + "#tradeDate={}".format(date))

    # Make sure we constructed the URL correctly
    print(resp.url)

    # Print the date that is being displayed
    soup = browser.get_current_page()
    print(soup.find('select', id='cmeTradeDate').find('option', attrs={'selected': 'selected'}).text)
```

The output looks like (ignore the syntax highlighting...):

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html#tradeDate=12/21/2017
Thursday, 21 Dec 2017 (Prelim)
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html#tradeDate=12/20/2017
Thursday, 21 Dec 2017 (Prelim)
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html#tradeDate=12/19/2017
Thursday, 21 Dec 2017 (Prelim)
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html#tradeDate=12/18/2017
Thursday, 21 Dec 2017 (Prelim)
http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/e-mini-sandp500_quotes_settlements_futures.html#tradeDate=12/15/2017
Thursday, 21 Dec 2017 (Prelim)
```

Unless someone knows of an alternative way to process this page with HTTP, I think your best bet is to use a tool that can interact with JavaScript, such as Selenium, which simulates a real browser.

Comment: Daniel much thanks for your explanation. As you told I tried it with Selenium. It works fine!